# If $N_{\mid\Lambda = \lambda} \sim$ Poisson ($\lambda$) and $\Lambda \sim$ unif$(0,5)$, find the probability of zero occurring.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution

The number of storms in the upcoming rainy season is assumed to be Poisson distributed, but with a parameter $\Lambda$ that is also random and uniformly distributed on $(0,5)$. That is, $\Lambda \sim$ unif$(0,5)$ and given that $\Lambda = \lambda$, the conditional distribution of the number of storms $N$ is Poisson with mean $\lambda$: $N_{\mid\Lambda = \lambda} \sim$ Poisson ($\lambda$).

So far I've gotten (for the first parts of the question; not pertaining to the question below):

E$(N\mid \Lambda) = \lambda$

E$(N) = \frac{5}{2}$

Var$(N\mid\Lambda) = \lambda$

Var$(N) = \frac{55}{12}$

(It would be greatly appreciated if someone checked that)

Now what I need to answer is:

(i) Find the probability that zero storms occur this season (I think I need to integrate the pmf of Poisson distribution but I'm getting stuck)

(ii) Given that zero storms occur this season, what is the conditional distribution of $\Lambda$?

How do I go about answering these questions?

Comment: No, this is not about expectation or variance.  It is about mixed probability distributions.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I did not mean it as pertaining to the question. There were just two parts before my question asking for that and I was just hoping someone could verify they were correct.

Comment: Ah, I see, They are *mostly* correct, save that $\mathsf E(N\mid\Lambda) = \mathsf {Var}(N\mid\Lambda) = \Lambda$ (capital)

Comment: (That is, conditional expectations and variances "are not numbers" -- they are themselves random variables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $N\mid\Lambda=\lambda \;\sim\;\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda)$ you know:

$$\mathsf P(N=0\mid \Lambda=\lambda) = \dfrac{\lambda^0 \mathsf e^{-\lambda}}{0!}$$

Since $\Lambda\sim\mathcal{U}(0;5)$ you also know $f_\Lambda(\lambda) = \frac 1 5 \mathbf 1_{\lambda\in(0;5)}$

And you should know how to find marginal distributions.

$$\mathsf P(N=0) =\int_0^5\mathsf P(N=0\mid\Lambda=\lambda) f_\Lambda(\lambda)\operatorname d \lambda$$

Put it together.

For (ii) use what you know about conditional probability (Bayes' Rule).  The mix of probability densities and masses is not an issue for this question.

$$f_{\Lambda\mid N}(\lambda\mid n) \;=\; \frac{\mathsf P(N=n\mid\Lambda=\lambda)~f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)}{\mathsf P(N=n)}$$

Comment: Wouldn't $0!$ be $0$? And I thought you cannot divide by $0$?

Comment: @LindseyG $0!= 1$ by definition/convention.

Comment: @LindseyG  No, $0!=1$. It makes sense if you consider $k! = \prod_{\ell=1}^k \ell$, since then for $k=0$ you have an empty product -- which "defaults" to the identity element for multiplication, i.e. $1$.

Comment: $0!$ counts the ways to arrange no objects.  There's only one way to do that.  Thus we define $0!=1$ .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all your previous calculations look fine.

1. Recall that to find the unconditional distribution of $N$ can be computed by
   $$P(N = k) = \int_0^5 P(N=k\mid\Lambda = \lambda)f_\Lambda(\lambda)\,d\lambda.$$
2. Notice that you are told $N$, and so you are seeking the conditional distribution of $\Lambda$ given $N$, which is
   $$f_{\Lambda|N}(\lambda\mid k) = \frac{f_{\Lambda,N}(\lambda,n)}{P(N=k)} = \frac{P(N=k\mid\Lambda=\lambda)f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)}{P(N=k)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A possibility for (i): define the random variable (indicator) $X=\mathbf{1}_{N=0}$, so that
$
\mathbb{P}\{N=0\} = \mathbb{E} X
$.

Now, write 
$$
\mathbb{E} X = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[ X\mid \Lambda ]]
$$
so we can first deal with the random variable
$$
\mathbb{E}[ X\mid \Lambda ] = e^{-\Lambda}
$$
and then get 
$$
\mathbb{E} X = \mathbb{E}  e^{-\Lambda} = \int_{0}^5 e^{-x}\frac{dx}{5}
= \frac{1}{5}(1-e^{-5}).
$$